# Tool for building WebML (RIAs extended) diagrams?

Tags: modeling, rich-internet-application

Do you know of any free tool for modeling data, business logic and maybe presentation (UI, interactions, etc) of Rich Internet Applications (RIAs) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A good free tool that will lead you to most of those things on your wish list would be Eclipse.  For RIA-s you can look at the

- [Eclipse RCP and RAP bundle](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/indigosr2)
- "A complete set of tools for developers who want to create Eclipse plug-ins, Rich Client or Rich Ajax Applications (RCP+RAP), plus Mylyn, and an XML editor. In addition to the CVS Eclipse Team provider, it also contains the EGit tooling for accessing Git version control systems."

Alternately you can look at JavaFX with Netbeans.  There wasn't much tooling for JavaFX when I last played with it.  That will probably change as JavaFX gains in popularity.

If you want something higher-level look around.  However if you are just getting going, I recommend you start there anyway because Eclipse promises a lot of different modelling and build tools.

Answer (score 0):

[WebRatio](http://www.webratio.com) actually includes already support for basic RIA and AJAX behavior. The tool can also be used together with [RUX-Tool](http://www.homeria.com) if very advanced and complex dynamic pages are needed.
Furthermore, [WebML](http://www.webml.org) will soon evolve into [IFML](http://www.ifml.org), which is under evaluation as an OMG standard. IFML will be a more comprehensive language that will natively include custom event management and rich interaction (not bound only to web interfaces).

[Disclaimer: I'm with Politecnico di Milano and WebRatio, and among the inventors of WebML/IFML]

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know tools bu here are Domain Specefic Language  :
for data you use entity–relationship model (ER model)
For Business Logic You Shoud Use Business Process Modeling Language (BPML)
For UX and UI you can use both WebMl ( Web Modeling Language ) or Interaction Flow Modeling Language (IFML) , however i love webml but is is being replaced by IFML .

you can google now for specefic tools for each language .